# Redirect after uploading to S3 from rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple file upload field:"

```
<form action="<%= @post.url %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_file_tag">
    <% @post.fields.each do |name, value| %>
      <input type="hidden" name="<%= name %>" value="<%= value %>"/>
    <% end %>
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-awaken btn-sm">
</form>
```

that I took from the [S3 online docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/PresignedPost.html).  The only issue is that it redirects to the S3 object after upload rather than simply returning to the same page.

**How can I change the form to accomplish this?**  I tried changing the form to rails helpers, but the upload would fail due to the automatic `accept-charset="UTF-8"` param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form should contain a field for the success_action_redirect option, which has the value of the URL you would like to redirect the user to following a successful post.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/PresignedPost.html#success_action_redirect-instance_method

Comment: ahh amazing!  I figured this was Rails specific and not S3